# Convert a swift sorted method to objective-c

Tags: objective-c, swift, sorting

What is the best way to convert this objective-c sorting method?

```
let visibleViews = self.scrollView.visibleViews().sorted(by: {$0.frame.origin.x > $1.frame.origin.x} )
```

I convert to :

```
[visibleViews sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIView *obj1, UIView *obj2) { return obj1.frame.origin.x > obj2.frame.origin.x; }];
```

I want to sort values to put the view with the larger xOrigin first (so the first item in the array will be the view on the right side of the screen). But I don't get the expected result.

Comment: *“But I don't get the expected result.”* is not constructive. What is the input, expected output, and actual output? Please post a [mcve]. – Are you aware that the Swift code *returns* the sorted array, whereas the Objective-C code sorts the array in-place?

Comment: Using the `>` operator does not give the required `NSComparisonResult` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of the `sortUsingComparator` block is `NSComparisonResult`. But your implementation is returning a type of `BOOL`.

One solution would be to use:

```
[visibleViews sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIView *obj1, UIView *obj2) {
    return [@(obj1.frame.origin.x) compare:@(obj2.frame.origin.x)];
}];
```

Note that a complete translation would be:

```
NSArry *visibleViews = [[self.scrollView visibleViews] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIView *obj1, UIView *obj2) {
    return [@(obj1.frame.origin.x) compare:@(obj2.frame.origin.x)];
}];
```